# If Lev Melech B'yad Hashem, why bother voting?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, malchut-royalty, politics-government, free-will-bechira

We have a concept in Jewish thought that rulers do not have free will concerning public affairs, based on the verse in Mishlei 21:1 'לב מלך ביד ה, the heart of a king is in the hand of Hashem (See commentary of the Malbim ibid).

That being the case, is there a point to voting, and if so, what is it?

Related: [Application of Lev Melech B'yad Hashem](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36004/4794)